# Want to change fonts back and forth using javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, button, fonts

I want to be able to change the font on a web page from its default CSS styled "Amatic SC" to Times New Roman for easier reading. I have a button that sucessfully changes it to Times New Roman, but can not change it back. My javascript is as follows

```
function changeFont(){
var fon = document.getElementById("posts");
    if (fon.style.fontFamily == "Amatic SC") {
        fon.style.font = "150% Times New Roman";
    }
    else {
        fon.style.font = "200% Amatic SC";
    }
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="posts">Content</div>
<button type="button" onclick="changeFont()">Change the font!</button>
```

CSS:

```
#posts {
  background-color: #F0F0F1;
  margin: 64px 64px 64px 64px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 200%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777777;
}
```

Comment: Try using `fontFamily` instead of `font`. If it works then...

Comment: I would probably create two css classes and check for existence of the class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always better to play with classes than font-family:

```js
function changeFont() {
  var fon = document.getElementById("posts");
  if (fon.className == "amatic") {
    fon.className = 'roman';
  } else {
    fon.className = 'amatic';
  }
}
```

```css
#posts {
  background-color: #F0F0F1;
  margin: 64px 64px 64px 64px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777777;
}
.amatic {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.roman {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="posts" class="amatic">Content</div>
<button type="button" onclick="changeFont()">Change the font!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't actually have that font.  Try switching to 'Arial' or 'Helvetica' or 'cursive'.

Comment: If he didn't have that font wouldn't it not work in the first place?

Comment: May have used a substitute.

Comment: Better to use css classes instead of looking for fonts.

Comment: Well I guess this is the only thing that could be wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

Made you a quick fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mikepmtl/hbL4L4py/

```
function changeFont(){

    var post = document.getElementById("posts");

    if (post.className == "post_normal") {
        post.className = "post_big";
    } else {
        post.className = "post_normal";
    }

}



.post_normal{
    font-size: 100%;
}

.post_big {
    font-size: 200%; 
}


<div id="posts" class="post_normal">
   This is my posts
</div>
<button id="my_button" onclick="changeFont();">Press Me</button>
```

Naturally you can add Font-family and anything else into the css classes.